# Laravel 5.2 & Git - Route not found

Tags: git, laravel, routes, laravel-5

I installed installed a fresh copy of laravel and developed an app.

My route file looks like:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['web']], function () {

    Route::get('/', ['uses' => 'PageController@index', 'as' => 'home']);

    Route::get('/agreement/SL/en/privacy-policy', ['uses' => 'PageController@privacyPolicy', 'as' => 'privacyPolicy']);

    Route::get('/agreement/SL/en/terms-of-use', ['uses' => 'PageController@termsOfUse', 'as' => 'termsOfUse']);

});
```

I developed it in my desktop and it works perfectly fine. Then and pushed it to the private git repository. Then when I take my laptop and make a clone of it, the landing page aka the '/' route works. But all the other routes does not work.

My gitignore file is:

```
/node_modules
/public/storage
Homestead.yaml
Homestead.json
```

PS:
i tried running :

```
composer install
composer update
clear compiled
```

etc.

When I go to other routes, i get this error:

```
Sorry, the page you are looking for could not be found.

1/1

NotFoundHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 161:
in RouteCollection.php line 161
at RouteCollection->match(object(Request)) in Router.php line 821
at Router->findRoute(object(Request)) in Router.php line 691
at Router->dispatchToRoute(object(Request)) in Router.php line 675
at Router->dispatch(object(Request)) in Kernel.php line 246
at Kernel->Illuminate\Foundation\Http\{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 52
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in CheckForMaintenanceMode.php line 44
at CheckForMaintenanceMode->handle(object(Request), object(Closure))
at call_user_func_array(array(object(CheckForMaintenanceMode), 'handle'), array(object(Request), object(Closure))) in Pipeline.php line 136
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 32
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 102
at Pipeline->then(object(Closure)) in Kernel.php line 132
at Kernel->sendRequestThroughRouter(object(Request)) in Kernel.php line 99
at Kernel->handle(object(Request)) in index.php line 53
```

Comment: what if you add `index.php` to your url on your laptop? `http://localhost/folder/index.php/route` ??

Comment: Laracademy - :O , that works. why does this problem occur? and how come I didn't have to do this in my desktop?

Comment: What are you running on your desktop vs your laptop? Most-likely it is just configuration differences (eg; mod-rewrite, etc)

Comment: Laracademy, can you please tell me how to fix it? Because if I copy the file using a flash drive, the project works fine on the laptop.

Comment: first we would need to know what you are running; Valet, WAMP, MAMP, a server, etc.. and what is it, apache/ngix, etc

Comment: Last comment from me :)   Try following this guide to enable mod_rewrite on your configuration: http://www.leonardaustin.com/blog/technical/enable-mod_rewrite-in-xampp/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/118106/discussion-between-geeth-w-and-laracademy).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason was because of the URL.

Forexample :  my original project on my desktop was named:

**findMe**,

Then I pushed the project to a git repo named **findMe**.

But when I cloned the repo to my laptop , the folder gets named to **findme**. The **uppercase 'M'** **gets replaced with lowercase 'm'**.

Everything except the '/' URL does not work. I nearly wasted 6 hours of my life.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried running `php artisan cache:config`?

Comment: cache:config is not defined

Comment: I'm sorry, it's actually `php artisan config:cache`

Comment: Same issue, but it works this way :
http://localhost/folder/index.php/route

Comment: I remember having the same problem when I uploaded my files to the hosting server, but seems to forgotten how'd I fixed it. I know `composer update` automatically creates an autoload but `composer dump` is also worth a try. Somehow, I remember something with the directory structure. Not sure but have you modified your .env?

Comment: I've allowed the vendor folder to be uploaded to git. so I do not have to run composer update.

composer dump doesnot work also